# Error Packaging a Shell script with Autotools

Tags: sh, autotools, autoconf, automake

I'm trying to write a simple Autotool package that just packages a single script. This might seem like overkill, but the script is to be added into the build-system for an embedded system and the build-system is designed to play nicely with Autotools.

I have a shell-script called `wifi_query.sh`. To package this I've followed the following steps:

1. Created `Makefile.am` which contains the following -

   ```
   bin_SCRIPTS = wifi_query.sh
   CLEANFILES = $(bin_SCRIPTS)
   ```
2. I also created `wifi_query.sh.in` which contains the line `exec wifi_query.sh`. I'm not sure I understand the purpose of the `.in` file.
3. I then run `autoscan`.
4. Then I run:

   ```
   sed -e 's/FULL-PACKAGE-NAME/wifi_query/' \
   -e 's/VERSION/1/' \
   -e 's|BUG-REPORT-ADDRESS|/dev/null|' \
   -e '10i\
   AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE' \
   < configure.scan > configure.ac
   ```
5. Run `touch NEWS README AUTHORS ChangeLog`.
6. Run `autoreconf -iv`
7. `./configure`
8. `make distcheck`

When I run `make distcheck` I get an error saying: "*** No rule to make target 'wifi_query.sh', needed by 'all-am'. Stop.".

I don't understand this error, if anyone could give me any pointers that would be good. My suspicion is that the error may be due to `wifi_query.sh.in`, but I have very limited autotools experience.

Comment: Your own answer is correct, `wifi_query.sh.in` wasn't causing the problem; but neither should it be necessary. If it was, its purpose would be for swapping platform-dependent code into `wifi_query.sh`.

Comment: Consider using `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])` if you don’t have meaningful content for `NEWS`, `README` etc. You can then remove the empty files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I needed to replace the line `bin_SCRIPTS = wifi_query.sh` with `dist_bin_SCRIPTS = wifi_query.sh` in `Makefile.am`. Having done that everything seems to work.

Comment: This is not the correct approach.  If you use `dist_bin_SCRIPTS`, you must not use `wifi_query.sh.in`; just call the script `wifi_query.sh`.  If you use `wifi_query.sh.in` (which it seems you do not need; if you needed it you would understand its purpose), you must add `wifi_query.sh` to `AC_CONFIG_FILES` (in `configure.ac`)to generate a rule to construct it from `wifi_query.sh.in`

Comment: Yeah that's correct, I forgot to add that `wifi_query.sh.in` has now been removed from the package too.